# How does the performance of a java program increase on a multicore machine

Tags: java, parallel-processing, multicore

I have a very basic question on the performance of a program in a multicore environment.

If I run a simple java program like calculating the square root of a number or finding the nth fibonacci series in a multicore machine, how does the performance increase?

If it takes x milliseconds to run on a single core, does it mean it will take x/8 milliseconds on a 8 core machine? (Technically I don't see this is correct)

Is there a way we can calculate the performance improvement on a multicore machine?

Comment: This isn't a Java issue, and it's way too broad. It depends on the parallizability of your workload, and in particular on the critical path and the cost of reducing the output of subtasks.

Comment: This doesn't seem too broad. Perhaps a bit theoretical and potentially off topic. But it certainly could be answered.

Answer (score 1):

> If it takes x milliseconds to run on a single core, does it mean it will take x/8 milliseconds on a 8 core machine? (Technically I don't see this is correct)

And you would be right.

You would only see a performance increase if your program made use of all the computing units (cores) of your machine.

Now, if your code is parallelizable, AND you program it to be so, then you MAY witness a performance increase. Java offers plenty of solutions for that:

- `Executor`s;
- the fork-join framework;
- (parallel) `Stream`s.

However, the core condition remains: your code *must* be parallelizable to begin with...